# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies. Either include them or remove the dependency array**, I'm new to react-redux and working on this small project, I'm getting this error, I tried adding generatePopupVariation and generatePopupOption to the dependency array but doesn't work. Please help me solve this error. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Sass/Index.scss'
import { WishListContext } from '../../contexts/WishListContext'
import { ProductContext } from '../../contexts/ProductContext'
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

const Product = ({product, id, productIndex}) => {
    const{name, price, image, variation, option, unit, total} = product
    const {wishListState, wishListDispatch} = useContext(WishListContext)
    const {productState} = useContext(ProductContext)
    const [popupVariation, setPopupVariation] = useState(false)
    const [popupOption, setPopupOption] = useState(false)
    const [listVariations, setListVariations] = useState([])
    const [listOptions, setListOptions] = useState([])
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({})
    const [updateToggle, setUpdateToggle] = useState(false)
   

    useEffect(()=> {
        generatePopupVariation()
        generatePopupOptions()
    }, [productState])

    const updateLocalStorage = (products) => {
        if (products.length > 0) {
            wishListDispatch({
                type:"REPLACE_WISH",
                payload: products.map(item => item)
            })
        } 
    }

    const generatePopupOptions = () => {
        const products = productState.products
        if (products.length > 0) {
            const finedProduct = products.find(item => item.id === id)
            const priceOptions = finedProduct.data.priceOptions
            setListOptions(priceOptions[0].options)
        }
    }

    const generatePopupOptionContent= () => {
        if ( listOptions.length > 0 ) {
           const filtered = listOptions.filter(item => item.is_available !== 'No')
           return filtered.map((item, index) => <li key={index}><span>{item.option}</span><span>Price: {item.price}</span><div className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => changeOption(index, item.option, item.price)} >Select</div></li>)
        }
    }

    const changeOption = (index, option, price) => {
        const action = {
            id,
            option,
            price
        }
        if (option) {
            wishListDispatch({
                type:'UPDATE_OPTION_WISH',
                action
            })
            updateLocalStorage(wishListState.products)
            modalOption('close')
        }  
    }

    const generatePopupVariation = () => {
        const products = productState.products
        if (products.length > 0) {
            const finedProduct = products.find(item => item.id === id)
            const priceOptions = finedProduct.data.priceOptions
            setListVariations(priceOptions)
        }
    }

    const generatePopupVariationContent = () => {
        if ( listVariations.length > 0 ) {
           return listVariations.map((item, index) => <li className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => changeVariation(index, item.variation, item.options)} key={index}>{item.variation}</li>)
        }
    }

    const changeVariation = (index, variation, options) => {
        const action = {
            id,
            variation
        }
        if (variation) {
            wishListDispatch({
                type:'UPDATE_VARIATION_WISH',
                action
            })
            updateLocalStorage(wishListState.products)
            modalVariation('close')
        }  
    }
    
    const handleRemove = () => {
        if (wishListState) {
            if( wishListState.products.length > 0) {
                wishListDispatch({
                    type: 'REMOVE_WISH',
                    payload: productIndex
                })
            }
        }
    }
    const handleUnit = (control) => {
        if (wishListState) {
            if( wishListState.products.length > 0) {
                wishListDispatch({
                    type: 'ADD_UNIT_WISH',
                    payload: {index: productIndex, control:control}
                })
            }
        }
    }
    const modalVariation = action => {
        if (action === 'open') {
            setPopupVariation(true)
        } else if (action === 'close') {
            setPopupVariation(false)
        }
    }
    const modalOption = action => {
        if (action === 'open') {
            setPopupOption(true)
        } else if (action === 'close') {
            setPopupOption(false)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Popup
                open={popupVariation}
                closeOnDocumentClick
                onClose={()=> modalVariation('close')}
            >
                <div className="popup-content"> 
                    <ul>
                        {generatePopupVariationContent()}
                    </ul>
                    <span onClick={() => modalVariation('close')}>X</span>
                </div>
            </Popup>
            <Popup
                open={popupOption}
                closeOnDocumentClick
                onClose={()=> modalOption('close')}
            >
                <div className="popup-content"> 
                    <ul>
                        {generatePopupOptionContent()}
                    </ul>
                    <span onClick={() => modalOption('close')}>X</span>
                </div>
            </Popup>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-wrapper">
                        <div className="left">
                            <img className="card-img" src={ image } alt={ name } />
                        </div>
                        <div className="right">
                            <div className="card-remove" onClick={handleRemove}>
                                <i className="times" name="close"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 className="card-title">{ name }</h4>
                            { variation && <p className="card-variation"><span>Variation:</span><span>{variation} <span onClick={()=> modalVariation('open')} className="change-variation"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></span></span> </p>}
                            { option && <p className="card-option"><span>Option:</span><span> { option }  <span onClick={()=> modalOption('open')} className="change-option"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></span></span></p>}
                            <div className="card-unit"><span>Qty:</span>
                                <div className="card-units-wrapper">
                                    <i className="plus" name="add" onClick={() => handleUnit('+')}></i>
                                    <div className="card-units">{unit}</div>
                                    <i className="minus" name="remove" onClick={() => handleUnit('-')}></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p className="card-price"><span>Price:</span><span> {price} </span></p>
                            <p className="card-total"><span>Total:</span> <span>{total} </span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Product

 const products = productState.products
  67 |     if (products.length > 0) {
  68 |         const finedProduct = products.find(item => item.id === id)
> 69 |         const priceOptions = finedProduct.data.priceOptions
     | ^  70 |         setListVariations(priceOptions)
  71 |     }
  72 | }
```

Comment: Which line it points to for error , can you be more specific

Comment: @Coderboi I specified it now, sorry for the trouble

Comment: try console logging  "id" in there and also console log "products" . It's just that there is no product with that id. Tht's why you are getting 'data' of undefined in this line `const priceOptions = finedProduct.data.priceOptions` that means findProduct is undefined due to no matching id

Comment: `find` returns undefined when there is no matching id. you might wanna do something like `if(finedProduct) {  priceOptions = finedProduct.data.priceOptions;       setListVariations(priceOptions) }`

Answer (score 1):

It happens because because `priceOptions` is empty, it happened because find didn't find the item you want or because the products list is empty.

You can solve this breaking problem using [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) changing this line to:

`const priceOptions = finedProduct?.data.priceOptions`

But keep in mind that priceOptions can be null after this operation.

Comment: I made those changes then its throwing  
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined  
`if (products.length > 0) {    
  8208 |     const finedProduct = products.find(item => item.id === id);    
  8209 |     const priceOptions = finedProduct === null || finedProduct === void 0 ? void 0 : finedProduct.data.priceOptions;    
> 8210 |     setListOptions(priceOptions[0].options);    
       |                                ^  
8211 |   }    
  8212 | };`

Comment: The problem now is that you can't do:

setListOptions(priceOptions[0].options) because you price can be null.

So you can make:


setListOptions(priceOptions && priceOptions[0].options) but keep in mind that you can be setting an null state

Comment: new errors are popping up, can you tell me from where can I clarify my concepts to solve them